# SQL Server connection string in different editions

Tags: sql-server

I don't know, If connection strings have the same formatting/configuration for all of SQL Server editions or not?
For example is it different between Express and Enterprise?
Because in my tutorial source that I'm learning(Asp.Net Core MVC)the SQL Server is Express and mine is Enterprise.
For that I get error and I guess it's because of my connection string.
With Thanks

Comment: What is the error?  What is your connection string (less username+password)?

Comment: The error is : " ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString "

Comment: and connection string(in config.json file) is:"ConnectionString": {
    "BlogDataContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }

Answer (score 3):

No, they're not different, but many times you have a different instance name.  A lot of times when SQL Express is installed, it gets installed to an instance name of SQLEXPRESS, so, for example, your local host instance might have to be referred to as ".\SQLEXPRESS" instead of ".", "(local)", "localhost", or "".

Comment: Thanks for answering